# Determine whether or not an array of integers has unique items

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a method that will compare values in an array of random integers. The method is supposed to check for uniqueness. The array would be considered unique if there are no duplicate integers, otherwise it is not unique. The curveball is I have to return a `boolean` value. It compiles but then it ends up crashing. Any suggestions?

```
public static boolean isUnique(int[] list) {
    boolean unique = true;

    do {
        for (list i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // cycle through array
            if (list[i] != list[i + 1]) // checks to see if first element is not equal to 2nd
            {
                unique = true;
            }
        }
    } while (unique);
    {
        if (unique == true) {
            System.out.println("This list contains all unique values");
        }
        return true; // if all values are unique return true
    }
    else 
             System.out.println("This list contains duplicates");
    return false; // otherwise the array contains dublicate
}
```

Comment: Always post the errors you get. Basically, don't tell us what you need. Tell us why/how it doesn't work.

Comment: I have properly indented your code using an IDE's autoformatter. You really have to do this yourself; look at the braces: sometimes there are too many and sometimes there are too few. That's a guarantee for errors. You also seem to have a floating `else` statement.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Have you even tried to debug it before posting the question to stackoverflow?

Comment: How is it compiling? where is if block for last else, what is list i = 0 in for loop?

Comment: Sheesh I was just stuck...

Comment: Please read the Help Center. You will get much better results if you learn how to use the site. You can always edit your question.

Comment: I understand, it would help if you took into consideration that not all of us are professional programmers. Some of us are just looking for help and are frustrated as it is. I'm doing the best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here--

First the crash-- you are checking against the next value in the list; however, when you are at the end of the list (i = array.length - 1) the next value will be off the end of the list.

Second, you probably can't assume the values are sorted beforehand, so you don't know that checking against the adjacent value will find all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead if all that code, you could let the JDK do the heavy lifting for you:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : list)
    set.add(i);
return set.size() == list.length;
```

If your `list` variable was *actually* a `List`, you could do it in one line:

```
public static boolean isUnique(List<Integer> list) {
    return new HashSet<Integer>(list).size() == list.size();
}
```

If you wanted to "overachieve", you could make this last version both generic, so it would work with any type, and work for any collection as well:

```
public static boolean isUnique(Collection<?> list) {
    return new HashSet<Object>(list).size() == list.size();
}
```

Note that a type of `Object` for the internal `Set` does not invalidate the correctness of behaviour - the set doesn't care what the type is, only that `equals()` and `hashCode()` for the type is correctly implemented.

Comment: Even with the `int[]` list, you could still just use `new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(list)).size() == list.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your method is actually wrong, you are entering infinite loop, have useless constructions

here is one of possible variant to check array for uniqueness:

```
public static boolean isUnique(final int[] list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++)
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < list.length; j++)
            if (list[i] == list[j])
                return false;
    return true;
}
```